# PHP LDAP trying to rename group but gettting - Naming voilation error

Tags: php, ldap, openldap

I am trying to rename group using PHP but i am getting error **Naming voilation**

Following is my code which successfully connects to LDAP server.
Everything is working fine just need to know how fix this error.

```
$ldap = ldap_connect("my_ldap_host");
if ($ldap) {

    $bind_rdn = "my_bind_rdn";
    $bind_password = "my_bind_password";
    $is_binded = ldap_bind($ldap, $bind_rdn, $bind_password);
    if($is_binded) {

        $ldap_ou = "my_ou";
        $ldap_base_dn = "my_base_dn";

        $group_entry = array();
        $group_entry["cn"] = $group_new_name;
        $group_dn = "cn=" . $group_old_name . ",ou=" . $ldap_ou . "," . $ldap_base_dn;
        $is_modified = ldap_modify($ldap, $group_dn, $group_entry);
        if($is_modified) {
            echo "Success";
        }
        else {
            echo "Fail : " . ldap_err($ldap);
            // here getting error Naming voilation
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Binding failed";
    }
}
else {
    echo "Fail to connect to LDAP server";
}
```

Comment: First time i am seeing `LDAP` code in php. Wondering what it does actually

Answer (score 2):

This needs to happen. You are trying to modify the `cn` of an entry that has the `cn` as pat of the `dn`. So you will need to modify the `cn` as well.

You'll need to perform something like this:

```
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
$is_modified = ldap_rename($ldap, $group_dn, $group_entry, NULL, TRUE);
if($is_modified) {
    echo "Success";
}
else {
    echo "Fail : " . ldap_err($ldap);
    // here getting error Naming voilation
}
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, i have made some modification to make it work, do you have idea how to force rename group if it has sub entries in it

Comment: You will have to rename all subentries as well! There's no other way!

Comment: The relevant "modification" was to change ```$group_entry``` from an array to a string that contains ```'cn=' . $group_new_name``` - everything else seems the same ;) Oh! and the 3rd parameter is  **not** a DN but an RDN. ;)

Answer (score 1):

@heiglandreas thanks for your input.

It very close to what i was trying to do. But in this code following modification is needed to make it work.

```
$is_modified = ldap_rename($ldap, $group_dn, $group_entry, NULL, TRUE);
```

to

```
$is_modified = ldap_rename($ldap, $group_old_dn, $group_new_dn, $new_parent, TRUE);
```

**$group_entry** : needs to be **String** not **Array** so i have used **$group_new_dn** as string instead of **$group_entry**

Full working code

```
$ldap = ldap_connect("my_ldap_host");
if ($ldap) {

    $bind_rdn = "my_bind_rdn";
    $bind_password = "my_bind_password";
    $is_binded = ldap_bind($ldap, $bind_rdn, $bind_password);
    if($is_binded) {

        $ldap_ou = "my_ou";
        $ldap_base_dn = "my_base_dn";

        $group_old_dn = "cn=my_old_group_name" . ",ou=" . $ldap_ou . "," . $ldap_base_dn;
        $group_new_dn = "cn=my_new_group_name";
        $new_parent = null;
        $is_modified = ldap_rename($ldap, $group_old_dn, $group_new_dn, $new_parent, TRUE);
        if($is_modified) {
            echo "Success";
        }
        else {
            echo "Fail : " . ldap_err($ldap);
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Binding failed";
    }
}
else {
    echo "Fail to connect to LDAP server";
}
```